# PHP object property in variable

Tags: php

I want to create dynamic object property as variable in php.
For example

```
$b = '';
if($b != '')  $b = "->b"; 
$a = new stdClass();
$a. $b->c;
```

My Target Output is

```
If(b == '') $a->c;
else $a->b->c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `$b->c` to work, you have to make `$b` an object of `stdClass` class. But since you made `$b` as a string using `$b = "->b";`, the former statement `$b->c` would throw error.

So the workaround is - make `b` as a property of object `$a` and assign an object of class `stdClass` to this member property. The following block of code would make this concept more clearer.

```
$b = '';
$a = new stdClass();
if($b != ''){
    $a->b = new stdClass();
    $a->b->c = 'something';
}else{
    $a->c = 'something else';
}
```

Later, you can have the desired target output like this:

```
if($b == '') echo $a->c;
else echo $a->b->c;
```